# How to process tr across all files in a directory and output to a different name in another directory?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, xargs, tr

```
 mpu3$ echo * | xargs -n 1 -I {} | tr "|" "/n"
```

which outputs:

```
@.txt
ag.txt
bg.txt
bh.txt
bi.txt
bid.txt
dh.txt
dw.txt
er.txt
ha.txt
jo.txt
kc.txt
lfr.txt
lg.txt
ng.txt
pb.txt
r-c.txt
rj.txt
rw.txt
se.txt
sh.txt
vr.txt
wa.txt
```

is what I have so far. What is missing is the output; I get none. What I really want is to get a list of txt files, use their name up to the extension, process out the "|" and replace it with a LF/CR and put the new file in another directory as [old-name].ics. HALP. THX in advance. - Idiot me.

Comment: Are you trying to use `tr` on the contents of the files, or the names of the files?  Sample input and desired output would help a whole lot

Comment: On the contents of each file.

Comment: I don't have any problem using tr alone on each file one-by-one, I just need help putting that in an automated way using xargs.

Comment: "echo * | xargs -n 1 -I {} | tr "|" "/n"" if I add the output file using ">" I don't know what to do using xargs.

Comment: Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45268144/edit) your question so it shows us an example of the files you are working with and what you want it to look like when it's done

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the files and use `sed` to process the file:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    sed -e 's/|/\n/g' "$i" > other_directory/"${i%.txt}".ics
done
```

No need to use `xargs`, especially with `echo` which would risk the filenames getting word split and having globbing apply to them, so could well do the wrong thing.

Then we use `sed` and use `s` to substitute `|` with `\n` `g` makes it a global replace.  We redirect that to the other director you want and use `bash`'s parameter expansion to strip off the `.txt` from the end

Comment: I can read this well and thank you. It will create a file named "bg.txt.ics" yes? How can I just get the name up to the extension process that same way?

Comment: meaning the output file is named "bg.ics".

Comment: @usermac no, with `${i%.txt}` we get the name of the file without the `.txt` at the end, and add `.ics`, if you won't want it in another directory remove the `other_directory/` part after `>`

Comment: Perf. Great, great, great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk solution:

```
$ awk '
FNR==1 {                          # for first record of every file
    close(f)                      # close previous file f
    f="path_to_dir/" FILENAME     # new filename with path
    sub(/txt$/,"ics",f) }         # replace txt with ics
{
    gsub(/\|/,"\n")               # replace | with \n
    print > f }' *.txt            # print to new file
```

Comment: Thank you and I'll try this as well. I like awk what little I've seen and used of it.